# EF CORE LINQ date comparison with new DateTime(yearId, monthId, dateId)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to execute a LINQ query against the `DbSet` in the EF context.  The `LastDAyToEnterData` class in the `DbSet` class has 3 get/set properties of short type, and is mapped to a SQL Server table with 3 columns of `smallint` type for year, month, day respectively.  When I use expression in the `.Where()`, I got this error.  What expression should I use to compare two dates?  Thanks.

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```
DbSet<LastDayToEnterData>
    .Where(l => new DateTime(
        (int)l.YearID, 
        (int)l.MonthID, 
        (int)l.StopEnteringDataAfter
    ) > new DateTime(
        DateTime.Today.Year - 1, 
        10, 
        1
    ))
```

Comment: Due to time constraint, I abandoned the approach to convert the yearid, monthid, and stopEnteringDateAfter to real DateTime. I would try it some other time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  [DbFunctions.CreateDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createdatetime) to create new DateTime object and also project out comparing date out of Linq:

```
var compareDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year - 1, 10, 1);

DbSet<LastDayToEnterData>
    .Where(l => EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(
        (int)l.YearID, 
        (int)l.MonthID, 
        (int)l.StopEnteringDataAfter
    ) > compareDate )
```

Comment: I changed it to .Where(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(x.YearID, x.MonthID, x.StopEnteringDataAfter,0,0,0) >= _fyStartDate) but still no luck.  It also says thatEntityFunctions is obsolete and should be replaced with System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.  That didn't work either.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you also need project out your comparing date out of linq.

Comment: Due to time constraint, I abandoned the approach to convert the yearid, monthid, and stopEnteringDateAfter to real DateTime.  I would try it some other time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The reason is that implicit client evaluation has been disabled in EF Core 3.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

As a workaround,you could change like below:

1.Model:

```
public class LastDayToEnterData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int YearID { get; set; }
    public int MonthID { get; set; }
    public int StopEnteringDataAfter { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.Controller:

```
var date = _context.LastDayToEnterData.Select(u => new { u.MonthID, u.YearID, u.StopEnteringDataAfter,u.Id }).ToList();
var list = new List<LastDayToEnterData>();
foreach(var d in date)
{
    var ConvertDate = new DateTime(d.YearID,d.MonthID, d.StopEnteringDataAfter);
    if(ConvertDate > new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year - 1, 10, 1))
    {
        var data = _context.LastDayToEnterData
                           .Where(l => d.Id == l.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        list.Add(data);
    }               
}
```